# To display shapefile in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want the "shapefile" mentioned below in the code to be displayed inside the "sideFrame" of the tkinter window. But now, the shapefile is getting opened up in the another window which I don't want to. That is, I want to display the "shapefile" inside the right frame of the "tkinter" window.I am new to this field, so could be clear with the explanation along with the code.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # for backend
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def forSubmit():
    if MyVar1.get()== 0 or MyVar2.get()==0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Select input files!")
    fp = r"F:\ISRO\Spatial_Data\grid_jagalur_spatialjoin.shp"
    data = gpd.read_file(fp)
    print (type(data))
    data.head()
    data.plot()
    plt.show(sideFrame)                                                                         

middleFrame = LabelFrame(root,width=800,text="Input data")
middleFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=8, pady=8, sticky=N+S+W+E)
middleFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
middleFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
middleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
middleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)      

Button6 = Button(middleFrame, text="View", command=forSubmit)
Button6.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, pady=4,sticky=E) 

sideFrame = LabelFrame(root,width=500, bg="powder blue", text="Image")
sideFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=8, pady=8, sticky=N+S+W+E, rowspan=3)
sideFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
sideFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
sideFrame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
sideFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
sideFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Comment: Can you cut your code down to a [mcve]?

Comment: I have edited the question.. Could you please check it  @Haem

Comment: That is better.

Comment: Alright.. May I get the solution..@Haem

Comment: I don't know matplotlib or tkinter very well, I could only advise you on how to improve your question so someone who does can figure your problem out more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a FigureCanvasTkAgg widget to your *sideFrame* and then try something on the following lines:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1)
cavnas_plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = sideFrame)
canvas_plot.draw()
canvas_plot.get_tk_widget.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

Ensure that there is enough space for the *sideFrame* to be visible on the main window

Comment: Don't use pyplot figures in a custom canvas. See the [documentation example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) (note how it does not use `pyplot` at all). Apart, this is probably not very helpful concerning the problem in the question, which asks about plotting a shapefile.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest could you explain as to why using pyplot figures in a custom canvas is wrong? I might be missing something in the documentation example. But, I have used it in several scripts and it works.

Comment: If your figure is managed by pyplot as well as your custom GUI, it can inevitably lead to conflicts. If you know what you're doing or are lucky, you may not run into such conflicts. The documentation example does not use `pyplot`. So if you stick to it, you're on the safe side.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest as far as I can tell, the only interaction that the custom GUI has with the figure is at **draw**, wihch just draws the figure using the renderer. And the figure used to draw is provided by pyplot. Do correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: It is not "provided" by pyplot, but pyplot still manages this figure. It's like with a child after their parents divorced. Both parents manage the child, and if they want to go on vacation, each in a different country, where will the child end up?